# ActionBarSherlock + Google Maps API, Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, google-maps, styles, actionbarsherlock

First of all, I know there are thousens of post asking the same, but after few days looking for a valid answer and try everything I'm still having the same problem...

So let's expose my situation:

I'm using ABS + google maps, so my map view xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0PGmnrCR70lothfjc_sFGTdFtESQPOksYKQWYpw"    
        android:clickable="true" />


</com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView>
```

Few days ago everything was good, I was able to do my stuff in the app and everything. But suddenly I just made a little change, insert a framelayout to display more options in the screen. I tried to go back but was impossible...

I'm really deseparated, what can I do? maybe I can create a new project and paste all my code, but not really sure if it's going to work...

Any suggestions?

BTW my error code is this one

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why are you using ActionMenuItemView, an internal class, explicitly?

Comment: not sure right now why, but I think I followed some tutorial or some example, what you recomend? change it or remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve the problem, the error in the screen is still there, but just like a warining and when I execute the app same to work fine.

The only think I made, is change the specific layout of ABS and put a frame layout.